# CreateProcess don't work on all applications

Tags: c++, external, createprocess

I am writing a little GUI application that is used to start other external executables. It works on all the executables I want, except one. Here is the code I'm using:

```
CreateProcess(FullPathOfExternalApp.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo)
```

Is it possible that the external app has a built-in mechanism that prevents it from being executed by another executable?

Thank you very much

Comment: It might help if you told us something about the external application you're trying to start.

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to do API level programming on Vista and 7, but as I recall from articles, executables that have special UAC requirements (like, must run as administrator), e.g. specified in manifest, cannot be run directly by `CreateProcess` but must be run via `ShellExecute`. By the way do check your arguments. If my idea does not pan out you will need to PROVIDE COMPLETE SOURCE CODE in order to get answer (-1 for that, we're not telepaths!).

Comment: Use GetLastError to figure out what went wrong. Then update your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by getting the last system error and then formatting it and dumping it out, something along the lines of:

```
std::string getSystemErrorMsg()
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    ::FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL );

    std::string err = reinterpret_cast<const char *>( lpMsgBuf );

    ::LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );

    return err;
}
```

I would call a function like that right after CreateProcess fails and then pass the err string to [OutputDebugString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use something like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to monitor the output. Sometimes the OS can let you know why it won't do something you expect it to do, not always, but I would at least start there.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special in using `CreateProcess()` to start a program. Your problem is elsewhere. It might be a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit system (won't run), it can be missing dependencies, it can be something else related to the environment. Your best bet is to use Process Monitor utility to check the most likely reasons.

Comment: ok, it works with every executables I have tried except one. I really don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: Just a guess, but if the environment is not set (particularly PATH) then it may not be able to locate it's shared libraries.